# filter against search parameters django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

How can I check in the `get queryset` if the search param is empty or not, so I can further customize my search, I want it not to filter `queryset` for "today", if the search is not empty, can someone explain me how to do this?

ModelViewSet:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, filters    
from cms.restapi.pagination import StandardResultsOffsetPagination
from cms_sales.models import LeadContact
from cms_sales.restapi.permissions.lead_contact_permissions import LeadContactPermissions
from cms_sales.restapi.serializers.lead_contact_serializer import LeadContactSerializer


class LeadContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = LeadContact.objects.none()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.has_perm('vinclucms_sales.can_view_full_lead_contact_list'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.all()
        elif user.has_perm('vinclucms_sales.can_view_lead_contact'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.filter(account_handler=user)

        filter_date = self.request.query_params.get('filter_date', None)

        if filter_date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date=filter_date)

        return queryset

    serializer_class = LeadContactSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)

    filter_fields = ('account_handler',)

    ordering_fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_handler__first_name', 'account_handler__last_name',
        'sub_organization_name', 'organization_name', 'next_action_date', 'serial_number',
        'status_text')

    search_fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_handler__first_name', 'account_handler__last_name',
        'sub_organization_name', 'organization_name', 'next_action_date', 'serial_number',
        'status_text')

    pagination_class = StandardResultsOffsetPagination

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, LeadContactPermissions]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but `query_params` should just be a `dict` so if it's not empty, then add your "today" filter.

Comment: yea, thanks for the hint, I was a bit confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I talked to my friend, we came up with a solution to my problem, so I've added a new `query_params` for the search and we added another clause to the `if` statement that I'm all ready using.

Additional clause is checking if the `query_params` on the request for searching/filtering is available and not empty, so if that is the case we don't add the **today** part to the `queryset`, so that the search is perform on the entire `queryset`.

the solution is:

```
filter_date = self.request.query_params.get('filter_date', None)
search_params = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)

if filter_date is not None and (search_params is None or len(search_params) == 0):
    queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date=filter_date)

return queryset
```